# How to automatically subset a dataframe based on certain columns and store in separate dfs in R

Tags: r, subset

I am working with a dataset in R. This dataset contains some columns of values and some columns of cities, each city as dummy variable (0 and 1). The dataset is something like this:

```
    df<-data.frame(A=c(1,2,2,3,4,5,1,1,2,3,4,4),
            B=c(4,4,2,3,4,2,1,5,2,2,5,1) ,
            C=c(rep(0:1, each=3, times=2)),
            D=round(rnorm(12, mean=50, sd=10), 2) ,
            City1=c(rep(0:1, each=6)),
            City2=c(rep(c(1, 0), c(6,6))))
```

The above dataset is a prototype. The real datasets have varying number of "City" variables, i.e. sometimes a dataset has 2 "City" column, sometimes it has 10 "City" column.
I want a solution that I can create separate datasets based on the values of each "City". For example, the codes creates a dataset based on the "1" values (not "0" values) in column "City1" and store in a dataframe with the name of "City1". Then, goes to the column "City2" and creates a dataset based on the "1" values (not "0" values) in column "City2" and store in a separate dataframe with the name of "City2". And so on.

I know that some codes like the below can do the job, but in this way I have to write the codes each time based on the name of "City" variables, and also the number of cities are varying in each dataset.

```
df1 <- df[df$City1==1,]
df2 <- df[df$City2==1,]
```

Does anybody can kindly help me in this problem?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want `split(df, df$City)`?

Comment: No. "split" creates two lists. I want one dataset for each "city" column, just when the values of City is "1". And this should be automatic for an unlimited number of "City" variables.

Comment: 'I want a solution that I can create separate datasets based on the values of each "City".' No, you don't want that. It will make every following step more difficult and inefficient. Splitting your dataset is usually a bad idea and it is always a bad idea if you don't even keep the subsets together in a list.

Answer (score 3):

Identify city columns, then loop through them and *split*:

```
#cc <- which(grepl("^City", colnames(df)))
# when cities start on 4th column.
cc <- 4:ncol(df)
lapply(cc, function(i){ split(df[, -cc], df[ i ]) })
```

**Edit:** to output list as separate dataframes into the environment, we need to name the list items then use *list2env*:

```
result <- unlist(
  lapply(cc, function(i){ split(df[, -cc], df[ i ]) }),
  recursive = FALSE)
# make unique names
names(result) <- make.names(names(result), unique = TRUE)

list2env(result, globalenv())
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. The problem is the name of cities will never start with "City" word. They are actually the names of different cities, like Chicago, NY, Tacoma, etc. 
But the city columns are always at the end of the dataset, for example columns 4 to 6 or 4 to 10 are always city columns. Do you have anything to identify the city columns based on the column numbers greater than 4?

Comment: @Oscar, edited the answer, just select 4th to the last column - `4:ncol(df)`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. It really helped me. There is one step left: I want to store those subsets in different dfs automatically. In the other words, I don't want to run separate code lines for each subset. There are tens of subsets in my original dataset. I just want that the outputs of your code automatically store in different datasets, with the df names equal to the name of each city. Is it possible to do that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Oscar edited the answer, read about list2env.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach using `purrr::map` and `rlang::bind_env`. This creates `df1` and `df2` in the global environment, watch out to not overwrite existing objects! If you just want a list of `data.frame`s then just stop with `map`.

```r
library(purrr)
library(rlang)

grep("City", names(df), value = TRUE) %>% 
  set_names() %>% 
  map(~ df[df[[.x]] == 1, ]) %>% 
  env_bind(.GlobalEnv, !!! .)
```

Data from OP

```r
df <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,2,3,4,5,1,1,2,3,4,4),
                 B = c(4,4,2,3,4,2,1,5,2,2,5,1),
                 C = c(rep(0:1, each=3, times=2)),
                 D = round(rnorm(12, mean=50, sd=10), 2),
                 City1 = c(rep(0:1, each=6)),
                 City2 = c(rep(c(1, 0), c(6,6)))
                 )
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can `paste` the columns and then `split`:

```r
Citys <- startsWith(colnames(df), "City")
split(df, do.call("paste", df[Citys]))
```

---

Or, with `pivot_longer`:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("City"), names_to = "Cities") %>% 
  filter(value == 1) %>% 
  split(.$Cities)
```

Use `list2env(your_list, .GlobalEnv)` if you want to convert the list into multiple data frames in your global environment.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. The problem is the name of cities will never start with "City" word. They are actually the names of different cities, like Chicago, NY, Tacoma, etc. 
But the city columns are always at the end of the dataset, for example columns 4 to 6 or 4 to 10 are always city columns. Do you have anything to identify the city columns based on the column numbers greater than 4?

Answer (score 0):

You can subset `df` for the columns starting with *City* using `startsWith`, test them if they are equal 1 `== 1` and get the column where this is the case with `max.col`. `Paste` *df* infront of the column ans use this to `split` `df`. Use `list2env` to get the `data.frames` in the global environment.

```
list2env(split(df, paste0("df", max.col(df[startsWith(names(df), "City")] ==
                                        1))), globalenv())

df1
#   A B C     D City1 City2
#7  1 1 0 65.30     1     0
#8  1 5 0 45.81     1     0
#9  2 2 0 43.37     1     0
#10 3 2 1 55.14     1     0
#11 4 5 1 59.21     1     0
#12 4 1 1 50.55     1     0

df2
#  A B C     D City1 City2
#1 1 4 0 62.32     0     1
#2 2 4 0 45.78     0     1
#3 2 2 0 54.80     0     1
#4 3 3 1 44.96     0     1
#5 4 4 1 61.42     0     1
#6 5 2 1 51.26     0     1
```

In case to keep it in a list and assuming City is only coded with 0 or 1 you can try:

```
split(df, max.col(df[startsWith(names(df), "City")]))
```

Or using `lapply` and subset `df`.

```
lapply(df[startsWith(names(df), "City")], \(i) df[i==1,])
```

---

Benchmark

```
bench::mark(check = FALSE,
zx8754 = {cc <- which(grepl("^City", colnames(df)))  #Returns something different
  lapply(cc, function(i){ split(df[, -cc], df[ i ]) })},
TimTeaFan = {grep("City", names(df), value = TRUE) %>% 
  set_names() %>% 
  map(~ df[df[[.x]] == 1, ])},
Maël = split(df, do.call("paste", df[startsWith(colnames(df), "City")])),
GKi = split(df,  max.col(df[startsWith(names(df), "City")])),
GKi2 = lapply(df[startsWith(names(df), "City")], \(i) df[i==1,])
)
#  expression      min median itr/s…¹ mem_al…² gc/se…³ n_itr  n_gc total…⁴ result
#  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:>   <dbl> <bch:by>   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <bch:t> <list>
#1 zx8754        495µs  548µs   1621.  11.27KB    10.3   788     5   486ms <NULL>
#2 TimTeaFan     226µs  247µs   3863.       0B    12.3  1877     6   486ms <NULL>
#3 Maël          250µs  264µs   3754.       0B    12.3  1824     6   486ms <NULL>
#4 GKi           302µs  321µs   3051.     240B    12.4  1480     6   485ms <NULL>
#5 GKi2          161µs  177µs   5575.   6.36KB    14.5  2694     7   483ms <NULL>
```